# PHP form hides after page refresh instead of just after submission?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, session

Here is the code I am using to hide the form

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php if(!$_SESSION['login']) echo 'style="display:none;"'; else echo 'style="display:block;"';?>/>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Hey, <?php echo ''.$_SESSION['user'].''; ?></p>
<input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Logout'){
session_destroy();
$_SESSION['login'] = false;
}
?>
```

I have to however refresh the page to hide the form. From what I know I think $_SESSION['login'] variable is being set after form submission. The first time I click on Logout, the page refreshes but some how the html displayed is not being refreshed(I am not sure). Then, After I click the Logout button again or refresh the page. The log out section hides itself.

Comment: Avoid copy & paste from tutorial or try to change something you not really understand.

Comment: I know what I am writing, Why did you think I copy pasted it?

Comment: So why you can't solve your problem ?

Comment: Because I am learning and I am bound to run into problems. Everyone gets stuck somewhere at some point.

Comment: Your form is plain html. If you want it hidden after some condition Ie. login wrap it inside php conditional statement. Or using javascript or jquery.

Comment: i have written <?php if(!$_SESSION['login']) echo 'style="display:none;"'; else echo 'style="display:block;"';?> in the div in first line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']='abc';
?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) echo 'style="display:none;"'; else echo 'style="display:block;"';?>/>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Hey, <?php echo ''.$_SESSION['user'].''; ?></p>
<input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
</div>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
session_destroy();
$_SESSION['login'] = false;
}
?>
```